# View is not getting refreshed in bindable layout xamarin forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

i am creating a horizontal list of categories by using a bindable layout in a stack view like in image shown below, so when i clicked on one of my category i want to change the text color but in actual Binding does not update view after the property changed has been fired.

[image]

```
                <StackLayout x:Name="CategoryStack" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryListItems,Mode=TwoWay}"
         Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,3,0,3" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <custom:PancakeView BackgroundColor="White"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsClippedToBounds="true" Padding="4" HeightRequest="47"  CornerRadius="5">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="Small"  Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="{Binding NameColor,Mode=TwoWay}">

                                    </Label>
                                </Grid>


                                <custom:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer  CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CategoryTappedCmd,Source={x:Reference CategoryStack}}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                </custom:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>

                            </custom:PancakeView>



                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
```

below is my ViewModel code

```
  public class ProductsListViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

    private ObservableCollection<SpicesCategory> _CategoryListItems = new ObservableCollection<SpicesCategory>();

    public ObservableCollection<SpicesCategory> CategoryListItems
    {
        get => _CategoryListItems;
        set
        {
            _CategoryListItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => (CategoryListItems));
        }
    }

  public ICommand CategoryTappedCmd => new Command(CategoryTapped);

    public async void CategoryTapped(object obj)
    {


        SpicesCategory SelectedspicesCategory = obj as SpicesCategory;

        foreach (var item in CategoryListItems)
        {
            if(item == SelectedspicesCategory)
            {
                item.IsSelected = true;

                item.NameColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                item.IsSelected = false;
                item.NameColor = Color.Black;
            }

        }

    }
 }
```

and below is my SpicesCategory model

```
public  class SpicesCategory
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public Color NameColor { get; set; }
}
```

below is my ViewModelBase inheriting ExtendedBindableObject

```
 public class ViewModelBase : ExtendedBindableObject
  {

    public ViewModelBase(INavigationService navigationService)
    {

    }

    private bool _isBusy;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get => _isBusy;
        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() =>(IsBusy));
        }
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public virtual Task InitializeAsync(object data)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
}
```

and below is my ExtendedBindableObject inheriting BindableObject

```
 public abstract class ExtendedBindableObject : BindableObject
{
    public void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
    {
        var name = GetMemberInfo(property).Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(name);
    }



    private MemberInfo GetMemberInfo(Expression expression)
    {
        MemberExpression operand;
        LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)expression;
        if (lambdaExpression.Body as UnaryExpression != null)
        {
            UnaryExpression body = (UnaryExpression)lambdaExpression.Body;
            operand = (MemberExpression)body.Operand;
        }
        else
        {
            operand = (MemberExpression)lambdaExpression.Body;
        }
        return operand.Member;
    }
}
```

Comment: Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on class SpicesCategory

Comment: @MaxHampton hi am actually using RaisePropertyChanged please check the above code now have updated it.

Comment: I see that you're implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your ViewModel class, but you aren't binding text color to a property on your ViewModel, it's bound to a property on SpicesCategory. In that case, you need property changed notification coming from the class that holds the property you are binding to. The changes should be firing from your foreach loop where you're setting item.Name and item.NameColor

Comment: ok I tried this just after my foreach loop 

        ObservableCollection<SpicesCategory> NewCategory = new 
     ObservableCollection<SpicesCategory>();

                NewCategory = CategoryListItems;

                CategoryListItems = new ObservableCollection<SpicesCategory>();

                CategoryListItems = NewCategory;

But it didn't work, problem is my UI part is not getting updated, my model is getting the updated value

Comment: All you should need is `SpicesCategory : BindableObject` and RaisePropertyChanged in the setters

Comment: can you please give me an example how to RaisePropertyChanged in setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can you please give me an example how to RaisePropertyChanged in
>   setters.

Try to change your `SpicesCategory` model to:

```
public class SpicesCategory :ExtendedBindableObject
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    private string _name { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => (Name));
        }
    }

    private Color _nameColor { get; set; }

    public Color NameColor
    {
        get => _nameColor;
        set
        {
            _nameColor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => (NameColor));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working now, just curious to know that why its not getting changed from my ViewModel as it is inheriting > ViewModelBase and ViewModelBase is inheriting > ExtendedBindableObject so  it should be updated from my viewModel and also my code works great for listview, it's just not working in some cases like this one.

Comment: When you set up a binding, you're telling your view, watch for the event PropertyChanged to fire on the object that holds the property you're binding to. The page has a binding context of the view model, but each cell of a list view for example has the binding context of the object in the collection that is bound to the list view's item source. Bindings within cells then watch for PropertyChanged to fire on those objects, not on the view model class